Can you have multiple GitLab CI CD Yaml Files?
I'm looking to create multiple pipelines for different jobs, such as running Checkov as an independent job whenever there is a merge request to the main branch.
I currently have a .gitlab-ci.yml file for my Terraform build. I'm transitioning from using GitHub Actions to GitLab CI/CD.


Can you have multiple GitLab CI CD Yaml Files?

No. Instead, you can have one big gitlab cicd that includes other files.

How do you mean? Is there any documentation that I can follow?

https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/includes.html https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#include

You can use individual jobs in a singular .gitlab-ci.yml or downstream pipelines to accomplish this. For example, a child or downstream pipeline could look like this:
trigger-checkov-pipeline-job:
  trigger:
    include: path/to/checkov-pipeline.yml
  rules:
    - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event"

Or you could include a checkov job in your current pipeline configuration:
stages:
    - test
    
checkov:
  stage: test
  allow_failure: true  # True for AutoDevOps compatibility
  image:
    name: bridgecrew/checkov:latest
    entrypoint:
      - '/usr/bin/env'
      - 'PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin'
  rules:
    - if: $SAST_DISABLED
      when: never
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH
      exists:
        - '**/*.yml'
        - '**/*.yaml'
        - '**/*.json'
        - '**/*.template'
        - '**/*.tf'      
        - '**/serverless.yml'
        - '**/serverless.yaml'
  script:
    - checkov -d . -o junitxml | tee checkov.test.xml
  artifacts:
    reports:
      junit: "checkov.test.xml"
    paths:
      - "checkov.test.xml"

